# Why the content of youtube homepage opengraph image is a bad url?

Tags: youtube, facebook-opengraph

I notice in the head section of www.youtube.com that the meta property="og:image" content is not a valid URL...
There I read: //s.ytimg.com/yts/img/youtube_logo_stacked-vfl225ZTx.png

A good one and the one which is readable by my browser is:
http://s.ytimg.com/yts/img/youtube_logo_stacked-vfl225ZTx.png

I am interesting to know why Google did this choice?

Thanks from France!

Answer (score 0):

The url that Google chose is called a **protocol-less** url. Depending on which protocol you are accessing youtube.com (i.e. http or https), the protocol of the image will change. So if you check you can actually access the image both by [http](http://s.ytimg.com/yts/img/youtube_logo_stacked-vfl225ZTx.png) or [https](http://s.ytimg.com/yts/img/youtube_logo_stacked-vfl225ZTx.png).

More interestingly even though facebook linter gives error, when you share the youtube.com home page on facebook, it actually picks the correct image.

Hope this helps.